# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_9

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, py4j

I am trying to execute spark-submit locally,

```
spark-submit --master local --executor-cores 1 --queue default --deploy-mode client test.py
```

but getting error

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext. :
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_9

I am using python 3.8 and pyspark 3.0.1, for java I have Open JDK 1.8

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error, when trying to call a local jar via sc._jvm. I managed to make it work by reverting to an earlier version of pyspark (2.4.3) in my case.

I am also using python 3.6.8 - I had a different error with pyspark 3.0.1 for python 3.8.